Fetching Data from Supabase to a Client Component NextJS14
I need help fetching data from Supabase to my Client Component NextJS. Here is my code.
The Component.tsx is just a sample page. But I need to fetch data to a client component because I have a page that uses 'useState'.
Thanks everyone!
//Component.tsx

"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/client";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const supabase = createClient()
        const { data, error } = await supabase.from("job_listings").select("*");

        if (error) throw error;

        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        // setError(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error}</p>;

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1>Data from Supabase</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item: any) => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;

